# Perl DAL Design Questions

Tags: perl, orm, data-access-layer

Recently I've been working on some Perl projects and I'm a very novice Perl programmer.  I've been experimenting with DBIx::Class and so far I'm really please with the flexibility and the ease of use.  I'm curious though.  I come from a .NET background and it seems like we spend a lot of time abstracting our DAL to a certain degree.  Is this a good idea with a language like Perl?

Where I want to get shortly is to have the ability to start mocking my DAL so I can write unit tests for tasks.  Right now though I'm struggling with how the overall structure and design of the application should look though?

Comment: Are you looking for the structure of directories typically used for different things like libraries, tests, etc?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure I have a decent directory structure with /bin, /lib, /t.  I'd really like to know about the relationship that the ORM should play in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re: Relationship of the ORM within the application...

Hopefully this is the kind of answer you are looking for...

With most web app frameworks in the "scripting" world (i.e. perl, ruby, python, php), most of the time I've seen the business logic implemented at the ORM object level. E.g. in a Rails app it's at the `ActiveRecord` level; if you are using `DBix::Class` it would be at the `Result`-class level.

More concretely, in the case of `DBIx::Class`, if you have a table named `VENDOR` there would be a class called `MySchema::Result::Vendor` which represents a single row in the table `VENDOR`. Simply add your business methods to this class.

One disadvantage of this approach is that it ties your business logic with the ORM class which can make (unit) testing more difficult. One solution to this is to use a light-weight database for unit tests (i.e. SQLite), and an ORM like `DBIx::Class` will facilitate switching between the two. Of course, this won't work if you rely on SQL features which are not implemented in SQLite.

Another approach is to place your business logic methods into a Moose role. Then those methods can be composed into either the DBIx::Class Result class or into a mock object for testing. I can elaborate with an example if you'd like.

One big assumption of the above is that your business object = one row in the database. If this is not the case (i.e. you business object spans more than one table), then you'll probably want to create a "shell" or container object which has as instance members each of the constituent ORM objects. Fortunately, Moose has a nice facility for delegating methods (search for `Moose delegation` and the `handles` attribute of instance member declarations), so it is relatively easy to make a composite business object out of two or more ORM objects. Again, I can give you an example of this if you'd like.

HTH

Comment: I've never used 'Moose' but it seems like the more I get into this perl endeavor the more I see that name popping up?  If you wouldn't mind with a simple example of mocking I'd appreciate it.  Otherwise I think you've answered my concerns.

Answer (score -6):

I used to work in perl projects for the web long ago. But after working with things such as Django, perl's tools like DBI, etc now look to me rather rudimentary and outdated. Have a look at the django ORM for example, it's elegant and very productive to use, you can bypass it if your query is too complex or the ORM gets in the way...

These days I'd go python or ruby for that kind of projects.
For one liners, small text parsing or sysadmin stuff I still love to use small perl snippets. But I'm more into DRY than TMTOWTDI for more than a few lines of code these days.

Comment: You know, that is something that I was wondering about.  Is perl dead?  It still seems like there is a big community, but with languages like python and ruby, it seems to have lost some popularity.

Comment: Perl is far from dead, it is undergoing a wonderful revival under the "Modern Perl" label.  DBI is indeed rudimentary and outdated, which is why we use DBIx::Class, which holds its own against django ORM.

Comment: DRY is looked for in Perl programming as well, it wouldn't be lazy to repeat yourself.

Comment: DBI is not an ORM, so you shouldn't compare it to an ORM. Look at DBIx::Class for Perl ORM.